# Python reshape to Matlab reshape translation

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I have the following Python code that I would like to run in MATLAB. What is the MATLAB equivalent of numpy's `reshape` syntax.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randn(3,4,5)
for i in range(len(a)):
    b = np.reshape(a, [a.shape[i], -1], order = 'F')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `-1` for a calculated dimension, you [would simply use `[]`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html#bud71ef-1) in MATLAB.

```
for k = 1:ndims(a)
    b = reshape(a, size(a, k), []);
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!